# Creating flags based on a column of lists in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where 1 column is a list of multiple movie genres for each movie. I need to create individual flags for each value that could be present in the lists. What's the easiest way to do this?

These are the 2 methods I tried:

```
df['g_Drama'] = ''
for i in range(len(df) - 1):
    if df['genre_list'][i].count('Drama') > 0:
        df.at[i, 'g_Drama'] = 1
    else:
        df.at[i, 'g_Drama'] = 0
```

```
df['g_Drama'] = ''
df.at[df['genre'].str.contains('Drama') == True]['g_Drama'] = 1
df.at[df['genre'].str.contains('Drama') == False]['g_Drama'] = 0
```

The 'genre' column is a column with the genres separated by ', ' like 'Drama, Action' while the genre_list column has them separated into a list like, ['Drama', 'Action'].

In the first case, I get the error: 'KeyError: 206' and in the second case, I get the error 'ValueError: Invalid call for scalar access (getting)!'

I am pretty new to Python and I've tried a fair few iterations to try and fix these errors, but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help woould be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please include a description of what you have tried, include your code, and any errors that you have received.  It may be helpful to visit [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help center.

Comment: Hi, apologies. I didn't know all the details expected of a proper question. In hindsight, I should have done my research before posting the question. Thank you so much for guiding me towards the proper resources, so that I could improve the question. Have a good day!

Comment: better use `df.iterrow()` instead of `range(len(df) - 1)`  - dataframes may uses different indexes then numbers `0... len(df)-1` . OR evern better `df.apply(function)`

Comment: or maybe even simpler `df['g_Drama'] = df['genre'].str.contains('Drama').sum()`

Comment: `df['g_Drama'] = ''
df.loc[(imdb_on_netflix['genre'].str.contains('Drama') == True), 'g_Drama'] = 1
df.loc[(imdb_on_netflix['genre'].str.contains('Drama') == False), 'g_Drama'] = 0` I finally got this to work. But I believe your idea might make this simpler. Thank you! @furas

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line

```
df['g_Drama'] = df['genre'].str.contains('Drama').astype(int)
```

or using `apply()`

```
df['g_Drama'] = df['genre'].apply(lambda item:int('Drama' in item))
```

I use `astype(int)`  because `int(True)` gives `1` and `int(False)` gives `0`

---

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'genre': ['Drama, Action', 'Western', 'Romance,Drama']
})

df['g_Drama'] = df['genre'].str.contains('Drama').astype(int)
print(df)

df['g_Drama'] = df['genre'].apply(lambda item:int('Drama' in item))
print(df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can use `for`-loop to do it for other genres.

```
for word in ["Drama", "Western", 'Action', 'Romance']:
    df[f'g_{word}'] = df['genre'].str.contains(word).astype(int)
```

Result:

```
           genre  g_Drama  g_Western  g_Action  g_Romance
0   Drama,Action        1          0         1          0
1        Western        0          1         0          0
2  Romance,Drama        1          0         0          1
```

---

**EDIT:**

Because you have lists - `'genre_list'` - so you can even join all lists using `sum()` and use `set()` to get unique genres and create flags for all genres.

```
all_words = set(df['genre_list'].sum())

print('words:', all_words)

for word in all_words:
    df[f'g_{word}'] = df['genre'].str.contains(word).astype(int)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
words: {'Western', 'Romance', 'Action', 'Drama'}
           genre        genre_list  g_Drama  g_Western  g_Romance  g_Action
0   Drama,Action   [Drama, Action]        1          0          0         1
1        Western         [Western]        0          1          0         0
2  Romance,Drama  [Romance, Drama]        1          0          1         0
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'genre': ['Drama,Action', 'Western', 'Romance,Drama'],
})

df['genre_list'] = df['genre'].str.split(',')

all_words = sorted(set(df['genre_list'].sum()))  # `set()` to remove duplicate
print('words:', all_words)

for word in all_words:
    df[f'g_{word}'] = df['genre'].str.contains(word).astype(int)
    
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are a few approaches.
Some Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'genre': ['Drama, Action', 'Western', 'Romance, Action'],
    'genre_list': [['Drama', 'Action'], ['Western'], ['Romance', 'Action']]
})
```

Assuming the `genre` column is uniformly formatted, in that each genre is separated by `', '` [`str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) works rather well without needing to use `genre_list` ([`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) is simply used to add all the resulting columns back to `df`):

```
df = df.join(
    df['genre'].str.get_dummies(', ').add_prefix('g_')
)
```

`df`:

```
             genre         genre_list  g_Action  g_Drama  g_Romance  g_Western
0    Drama, Action    [Drama, Action]         1        1          0          0
1          Western          [Western]         0        0          0          1
2  Romance, Action  [Romance, Action]         1        0          1          0
```

---

If going from the `genre_list` [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) the Series and pass to [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) then [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) to reduce dummies into a single row per index:

```
df = df.join(
    pd.get_dummies(df['genre_list'].explode())
        .groupby(level=0).sum()
        .add_prefix('g_')
)
```

`df`:

```
             genre         genre_list  g_Action  g_Drama  g_Romance  g_Western
0    Drama, Action    [Drama, Action]         1        1          0          0
1          Western          [Western]         0        0          0          1
2  Romance, Action  [Romance, Action]         1        0          1          0
```

While both produce the same results. `str.get_dummies` gets directly to the results without needing to explode and reduce, but requires strict formatting in the `genre` column.